# Issues with extracting Facebook Omniauth Authentication uid on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth, uid

I'm trying to extract and save in my db, the **uid** of a Facebook user's Omniauth Authentication.

When I issue the command **user.authentications**, the resulting array is displayed:

[ < Authentication id: 3, user_id: 63, provider: "facebook", uid: "123456789", created_at: "2012-07-02 02:10:48", updated_at: "2012-07-02 02:10:48" > ]

But when I execute **user.authentications.last**, to get the above Authentication out of the 1 item array, I receive:

< Authentication:0x007f837d32e288 >

Why doesn't it display all the parameters, **id, user_id, provider, uid,** etc. I can't access and extract the uid this way.  I'm trying to run **user.authentications.last.uid**.

Thank you

Comment: how do you call user.authentications if you have not saved to db yet? I save directly from omniauth request

Comment: I'm trying to get an index of all users. Some have signed up via Facebook, others via an email/password form. I give a conditional statement as follows:    <%@users.each do |u| %>
  
  <%if u.authentications%>
  
   <%=u.authentications%> <%=u.name%> 
   
  <%else%>
 
   <%=u.name%> 
  
  <%end%>
  <%end%>

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is simply different string representation of the objects.  `Array`'s `to_s` method gives you a nice printout, but `Authentication`'s `to_s` does not.  Try `user.authentications.last.inspect` if you just want to look at it.